# Copiar para o usuário oque está no INPUT quando clica no botão de copiar

Tags: php

Queria saber como faz para criar um botão que quando clicar, copiar oque está no input

Código do input e função:

Função:

```
    function geraSenha($tamanho = 18, $maiusculas = true, $numeros = false, $simbolos = false)
{
$lmin = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$lmai = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$num = '1234567890';
$simb = '!@#$%*-';
$retorno = '';
$caracteres = '';
$caracteres .= $lmin;
if ($maiusculas) $caracteres .= $lmai;
if ($numeros) $caracteres .= $num;
if ($simbolos) $caracteres .= $simb;
$len = strlen($caracteres);
for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
$rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
$retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
}
return $retorno;
}
```

Input:

```
<input name='AwardID' id='AwardID' type='text' maxlength='40' value='<?php echo geraSenha(18, true, false, false); ?>' readonly />
```

Botão:

```
<button id="copiarcodigo" type="button" onclick="" class="btn btn-default">Copiar código</button>
```

Comment: Eu estava a postar uma resposta com php, já que não havia javascript na solicitação... @bacco

Comment: @MagicHat PHP não tem como acessar o clipboard, ele rola no servidor. Como seria isso? Em principio me parece só uma tag errada, pq o problema é de JS.

Comment: Onde tá falando de clipboard ? ao meu ver ele quer copiar o que está no input e exibir pro usuário , não ?

Comment: MagicHat pelo contexto, o @Vinicius quer copiar a senha gerada para o usuário ao clicar no botão. Ou seja, pro clipboard. Se não for isso, só ele [edit] e explicar melhor.

Comment: Sem problemas... Favorece múltipla interpretações...Caso ele se manifeste...